# Go StartsWith(str string)

Tags: string, go, startswith

Is there a `StartsWith(str1, str2 string)` function that can check if `str1` is a prefix of `str2` in Go language?

I want a function similar to the [Java's `startsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [No startswith,endswith functions in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244048/no-startswith-endswith-functions-in-go)

Answer (score 235, accepted):

The strings package has what you are looking for. Specifically the HasPrefix function: http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#HasPrefix

Example:

```
fmt.Println(strings.HasPrefix("my string", "prefix"))  // false
fmt.Println(strings.HasPrefix("my string", "my"))      // true
```

That package is full of a lot of different string helper functions you should check out.

Answer (score 14):

For Example

If you want to check if a string starts with a dot

```
package main

import "strings"

func main() {
   str := ".com"
   fmt.Println(strings.HasPrefix(str, "."))
}
```

Terminal:

```
$ true
```