# No startswith,endswith functions in Go?

Tags: string, go

Just curious to findout: why aren't there standard functions like startswith, endswith, etc as part of the standard libraries in the Go programming language?

Answer (score 321, accepted):

The [strings](http://golang.org/pkg/strings) package contains [HasPrefix](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#HasPrefix) and [HasSuffix](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#HasSuffix).

```
import "strings"

startsWith := strings.HasPrefix("prefix", "pre") // true
endsWith := strings.HasSuffix("suffix", "fix") // true
```

[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/c8TQuCk-U9)

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with bytes, you can use these functions from the bytes
package:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "fmt"
)

func main() {
   fmt.Println(bytes.HasPrefix([]byte("Gopher"), []byte("Go")))
   fmt.Println(bytes.HasPrefix([]byte("Gopher"), []byte("C")))
   fmt.Println(bytes.HasPrefix([]byte("Gopher"), []byte("")))
}
```

It will be less costly than converting to string first. Useful if you are reading
in from an HTTP request, or reading from a local file.

- https://golang.org/pkg/bytes#HasPrefix
- https://golang.org/pkg/bytes#HasSuffix